# not all junit tests are running in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have a java project in eclipse, when I press the `project right click -> run as junit` some tests do not run. I attached a picture, see `YamiMailSenderTest` for example.
When I try to run the tests directly they are running.
I am using eclipse 3.7.2.

[image]

and expanded view:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: If you expand one of trees that were not executed, what do you see?

Comment: the same, tests with the same icon, all is empty.

Comment: The icon is not crossed out? So the test isn't annotated with `@Ignore`?

Comment: no, I will attach another picture

Comment: You haven't converted from Junit3->4 and missed some `@Test` annotations?

Comment: @DuncanJones - No, used junit 4 from beginning.

Answer (score 8):

Ran into the same problem, my error was that I wrote: `public void myMethodName(){ //assertions }`

instead of: `public void testMyMethodName() { //assertions }`

the test before the MyMethodName is important.

Comment: @If you could explain why JUnit tests must be prefixed with 'test', your answer would merit an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late, but in case anyone finds this via a search engine:

If a Test is run multiple times the results provided by JUnit are indistinguishable for those Tests and thus the results are only displayed for one run. See also the following Eclipse bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=172256

Answer (score 2):

Check if you are [excluding tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2383226/395659) from run by attributes and check under `Run > Run Configurations` if your JUnit configuration are excluding any tests.

Comment: That's seems to be OK. no ignored tests.

Answer (score 2):

In `jUnit 4`, a test case needs to have **@Test** annotation. The test case can be set to ignore with **@Ignore** annotation. The whole test class can also be set to ignore by placing the **@Ignore** annotation right above the class declaration. Note: In jUnit 4 , there is no need to extend Testcase class as in jUnit 3. Everything is in annotation.

I have no idea about jUnit 3 since I use only 4.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  For some reason, the "Run As -> jUnit Test" was always skiping the first test package.  I was on an older version of Eclipse and SpringSource.

I moved back to Juno - Version: 4.2.1 and all my test run when I perform:  "Run As -> jUnit Test. "

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Eclipse would only recognize and run 5 out of my 9 tests.  After much troubleshooting I found this trick to convince Eclipse to recognize the remaining tests: just open each file, hit space and then backspace to mark it as changed, and save it. Then, Eclipse will recognize it as a test.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it seems that cause was a combination of multiple factors. The right combination of properties was for me:

- The test class is declared as public
- The test methods are declared as public and NOT declared as static:

  public void testToTeXTable() {

despite what Eclipse may [say](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353394).

- Run as ... -> Run configurations should declare that (All methods) are tested and that JUnit 5 is used.[image: Correct run configuration]
- The imports in the test file contain the right source for the Annotation @Test, i.e:

  import static org.junit.Assert.*;
  import org.junit.Test;
  //import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;